# Generic Method in Java with out parameters

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to implement something similar to EventBus implemented in eshopOnContainers.

Is it Possible to define a method like this in java & read the meta data about T and TH at runtime ? There can be multiple classes extending IntegrationEvent(e.g. PriceChangedEvent) & we should be able to Identify the exact class name at runtime.

```
public <T extends IntegrationEvent, TH extends IntegrationEventHandler<T>> void subscribe() {
       
        
}
```

Comment: No. No runtime information is available in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass type info into method:

```java
        public <T extends IntegrationEvent, TH extends IntegrationEventHandler<T>> void subscribe(java.lang.Class<T> tClass, java.lang.Class<TH> thClass) {

        }
```

Probably [Guava Event Bus](https://guava.dev/releases/30.1.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/eventbus/EventBus.html) will be useful for you.

Comment: Yeah ended up doing the same. Thanks for the answer anyway.